# How to left-align IO stream operators << and >> in Vim?

Tags: vim, iostream, indentation, auto-indent

For example, instead of following alignment:

```
std::cout << "Hello " << "Hello "
  << "world ";
```

I want left-align the `<<` operator, as:

```
std::cout << "Hello " << " Hello "
          << "world ";
```

By default, Vim chooses the first one. Looks like it just increases the indentation by one level for the new line.

So, is there any way that I can get the second alignment by default?

P.S. I already tried the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin, but it aligns the region in a table, like:

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << "Hello "
          << "World"       << "World Hello".
```

which I consider too sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) and this works for me

```
:Tabularize /^[^<<]\S*
```

**Output:**

```
std::cout << "Hello World" << "Hello "
          << "world " << "World Hello";
```

**Explanation**

`^` Beginning followed by `<<` up to the to first `<<`, then the match will start exactly at the first `<<`.

Comment: this is the simplest way imho and you can setup similar rules easily in all of your other languages as well

Comment: Does not work well for me.  I would use `:Tab/\%(<<.*\)\@<!<<` instead.

Comment: @ib agree, thnx. I updated my answer to get rid of the extra space in my regex too.

Answer (score 1):

With the [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin, the command for aligning selected lines of text the way you want is `:<,>Align! l: <<`. The first argument is an AlignCtrl Command that tells it to left-align the first field and treat the rest of the line as a single field. The second argument is the separator. The Align manual explains all of the available arguments and pre-defined mappings.